# Weird goal `Some 0 = true` generated in proof

Tags: coq

Consider this toy Coq problem ([CollaCoq](https://x80.org/collacoq/osutuzoqiy.coq)):

```
Require Import ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool.
Require Import Unicode.Utf8.

Definition optfun (n: nat) : option nat :=
    match n with
    | 0 => Some 0
    | _ => None
    end.

Definition boolfun (n: nat) : bool :=
    match n with
    | 0 => true
    | _ => false
    end.

Lemma lem : ∀ n, isSome (optfun n) = boolfun n.
Proof.
    intro. unfold optfun, boolfun. destruct n.
```

My goal here was to have `boolfun` be true whenever `optfun` returns a Some, and to prove that in the lemma.

However, after the proof steps given, the current subgoal is `Some 0 = true`.

I thought a proposition like that should not even type check because I'd expect `Some 0` to be of type `option nat` and `true` to be of type `bool`. Why does this happen? Is there something wrong with my `optfun`, `boolfun` or `lem`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we run `Set Printing Coercions.`, we can see all the [implicit coercions](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/addendum/implicit-coercions.html) in our expression (by default, Coq hides them). In our case, the goal turns into `isSome (Some 0)`, because SSReflect adds a coercion between `option` and `bool`. By running `Set Coercion Paths option bool.`, we see that `isSome` itself is the coercion in question (see [this](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.12.1/stdlib/Coq.ssr.ssrbool.html#isSome) part of the standard library).